# How to store item of nested sortable item in database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, c#-4.0

I have requirement like this.I can drag and drop my  one Order list to another.
and Save also into Data base.
Again when reload same format will be display.
 I want to store Parameter like
DocumentCategory,
DocumentName,
Ordering

any one  can give the idea class structure and table structure?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the database you're using. However, if you decide to use MySQL, you can use [this](http://github.com/aggie2016/EasyMySQL) library that I put together recently to automate the whole process of storing/retrieval of user-defined classes. It also contains support for nested classes. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Miller.I want class structure for this storing and retraiving.